How to use DwmSetIconicThumbnail() with thumbnails smaller than the maximum width?
If DwmSetIconicThumbnail() is called with a bitmap having the exact width and height values given by the WM_DWMSENDICONICTHUMBNAIL message, the taskbar thumbnail is shown with the appropriate size.
If the bitmap passed to DwmSetIconicThumbnail() has a smaller width than the maximum allowed width, the taskbar thumbnail is shown stretched to the maximum width provided by the WM_DWMSENDICONICTHUMBNAIL message. If the taskbar button is hovered a second time, the thumbnail is shown with the correct width.
I expect the size of the taskbar thumbnail to be correct already during the first mouse over.
Is this a windows bug? If yes, can it be circumvented?
I have tried to call DwmSetIconicThumbnail() a second time using the same bitmap, but it does not fix the problem.
Reproduction:

Download and install the TabThumbnail Visual Studio sample project:
https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/main/Samples/Win7Samples/winui/shell/appshellintegration/TabThumbnails

Add the following code at the beginning of the _CreateDIB(int,int) method in TabWnd.cpp to decrease the target width of the thumbnail:
nWidth /= 2;

Compile and run the sample app.


First time mouse over:

Second time mouse over:


I used GDiPlus to load a bitmap, and then it has the same result when DwmSetIconicThumbnail call it. DwmSetIconicThumbnail definately has the exceptional behavior. You can report it to Microsoft directly. Send feedback to us so that it will attract more attention. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/send-feedback-to-microsoft-with-the-feedback-hub-app-f59187f8-8739-22d6-ba93-f66612949332

@Torrecto-MSFT Thanks for your comment. I have reported the issue to Microsoft

Link to Microsoft Feedback Hub: https://aka.ms/AAq67r5
Please vote for the issue if you experience the same problem.
